# Где взять API от Bitrix

Tags: api, битрикс

Хочу написать приложение, интегрированное с **Bitrix**, но никак не могу найти его **API**.
Целый день капаю инет и все не могу найти то, что нужно. Все мои поиски всегда приходят на [какой-то курс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=99&LESSON_ID=9287&LESSON_PATH=8771.9275.9279.9287).

Собственно сам вопрос: кто сталкивался с написанием приложений для **Bitrix** - где Вы брали **API** от него? Есть ли он вообще?

Comment: Ну судя по тому что они там говорят, это saas, а значит платно) https://www.bitrix24.ru/apps/api.php. Но там вроде есть кнопочка "получить бесплатно"

Comment: Да, вот [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/?_gl=1*1cpp7hk*_ga*MTIwNTM0MTk0OS4xNjU1Mzc2ODYy*_ga_5Y8F1JHJ1W*MTY1NTM3Njg2MS4xLjEuMTY1NTM3Njk0NC40Nw..*_ga_YLDC55MYKM*MTY1NTM3Njg2MS4xLjEuMTY1NTM3Njk0NC40Nw..) вот тут написано, что только на коммерческих тарифах, но у них есть бесплатный тариф (там перейдите по ссылке в статье)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В основном все прилождения работают по REST
документация по REST bitrix https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/

пример и курс по приложениям https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=99&CHAPTER_ID=08583&LESSON_PATH=8771.8583

Comment: Там везде написано bitrix24, а есть API для битрикс - Малый бизнес?

Comment: там нет приложений. есть модули и обічное api ядра
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/index.php